# Cannot read form values from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page which is a table full of forms. When I click submit it goes to a servlet which is suppose to read the values of the forms in the survey using the getParamValues method but it is not working. When I try to print out the String array from the getParamValues I keep getting nullpointerexceptions.

Here is the relevant servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    String[] nums = req.getParameterValues("questNum");
    out.println(nums[2]);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}
```

Here is the relevant JSP code, running on GAE:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="com.surveycreator.service.persistence.SurveyPersistence" %>
 <%@ page import="com.surveycreator.service.model.Survey" %>
 <%@ page import="com.surveycreator.service.model.SurveyQuestion" %>
 <%@ page import="com.surveycreator.service.model.Survey" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>


<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
<p>View Survey</p>
<form action="/storesurvey" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Survey" />
</form>




<%
SurveyPersistence persist = new SurveyPersistence();
String surveyName = request.getParameter("content");
Survey survey = persist.getSurvey(surveyName);
List<SurveyQuestion> question = survey.getSurvey();
out.println("<table border='1'><tr><th>QuestionNumber</th><th>Survey Question</th><th>(Yes/yes)(No/no)</th></tr>");
for (SurveyQuestion questionObject : question) {
    int tableCounterString = questionObject.getQuestionNumber();
    String quest = questionObject.getQuestion();
    out.println("<tr><td><form><input id ='question' name='questNum' type='text' readonly='readonly' value='"+tableCounterString + " ' /></form></td><td><form><input id ='question' name='quest' type='text' readonly='readonly' value='"+quest + " ' /></form></td><td><form><input id ='ans' name='answer' type='text' value='' /></form></td></tr>");


}  


%>
<%= survey.getSurveyName()%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That link leads to a HTTP 500 error page and is not particularly helpful anyway. Just post the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given as far, the only possible cause of a NPE is that you simply don't have *any* `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` element with a `name="questNum"` anywhere in the HTML form which submits to the servlet.

---

**Update** as per the JSP code: the submit button is indeed in a *different* HTML form than the input fields are. You need to put the submit button in the *same* HTML form as the input field is. Depending on the functional requirement -which is unclear at this point-, you need to move the submit button into the table cell, or to remove the `<form>` in the table cell and wrap the entire table inside a big `<form>`.

---

<sub>**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, mixing `doGet()` and `doPost()` is a poor practice in this particular case. If you ever open the servlet by entering its URL in browser address bar, without passing any parameters, then you will *definitely* get NPEs. Don't let them do the same. Use `doGet()` only to *preprocess* requests and use `doPost()` only to *postprocess* requests. As an example, all the Java code which you have inside the JSP *scriptlet* `<% %>` should be done in the `doGet()` method and the HTML code should be repeated by JSTL `<c:forEach>` tag.</sub>

Comment: I am sorry the link does not work, here is the code for the JSP, i should mention everything is on the Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many forms in your code. when you press Submit Survey button, there is no value will be sent to the servlet but the value of button.

Solution: (base on your provided code )

```
     <head>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
     </head>

     <body>
     <p>View Survey</p>
     <form action="/storesurvey" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Survey" />

     <%
     SurveyPersistence persist = new SurveyPersistence();
     String surveyName = request.getParameter("content");
     Survey survey = persist.getSurvey(surveyName);
     List<SurveyQuestion> question = survey.getSurvey();
     out.println("<table border='1'><tr><th>QuestionNumber</th><th>Survey Question</th><th>(Yes/yes)(No/no)</th></tr>");
     for (SurveyQuestion questionObject : question) {
         int tableCounterString = questionObject.getQuestionNumber();
         String quest = questionObject.getQuestion();
         out.println("<tr><td><input id
 ='question' name='questNum' type='text' readonly='readonly'
 value='"+tableCounterString + " '
 /></td><td><input id
 ='question' name='quest' type='text' readonly='readonly' value='"+quest + "
 ' /></form></td><td><input id
 ='ans' name='answer' type='text' value='' /></td></tr>");


     }  


     %>
</form> <-----(this is the change)
     <%= survey.getSurveyName()%>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Notice that I removed some  tag in your code.

try it out. If there is bug, please post here.
Hope this help.

NathanPhan